# Have multiple elements in a FlatList header

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Is there any way to pass an array of elements to a FlatList, without a wrapper, such that I could later use `stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}` to make only the second element sticky ?

My intent is to have a non sticky header together with a sticky toolbar and pass them to the component.

If I try to pass the renderHeader as a function to the ListHeaderComponent such as

```
  renderHeader = () => {
    const { toolbar, header } = this.props;
    const arr = [header(), toolbar()];
    return arr;
  };
```

I get a

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `VirtualizedList`.
```

What would be an alternative way of achieving that behavior (i.e) have a list where only the second header gets sticky?

Another approach I tried was to declare a scrollview  with 3 children:

```
The non-sticky header
The toolbar
The flatlist itself
```

while setting the `stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}` on the ScrollView.

This way I got the desired visual scrolling behavior (i.e the toolbar got sticky). However, with such approach I got issues with conflicting events between the outer scrollview and the inner flatlist, so I do not know if it's a valid approach either.

Comment: So far, as a very nasty workaround the easiest approach was to put 2 extra items into the data array, one for the non-sticky-header and another for the sticky-toolbar ({key:"_header},{key:"_toolbar"} and handle the renderItemMethod so that I would render these accordingly instead of my regular items. 
This way I could set the stickyHeaderIndices to my "second element" via stickyHeaderIndices={[1]} (which is actually the toolbar I needed to set as sticky in first place)
In the screen it works like a charm.
However, code-wise, it definitely stinks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a sectionlist with 1 ListHeaderComponent and 1 section with a sticky header. I've successfully done this before.

Comment: My question is similar to the actual question, but in my case, I have to make the first header sticky. Is it is possible using SectionList...is yes how?